# Worldproblem help

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Mina has $5$ more marbles than Kristy,
Kristy has $2$ more marbles than Seb,
altogether they have $30$ marbles.

How many marbles do they have each?

Comment: Hi Billy! Welcome to the forum. In order for us to help you better, it would be really great if you could tell us what you've tried so far and where you get stuck.

Comment: @rubik Did you really think this question was worth bringing back to the front page by that edit?

Comment: @mrf The question wasn't conforming to the site's guidelines. It is the duty of the users to keep the quality of the site at a bare minimum level. If you think the question was unsalvageable you should cast a vote. I apologize to you, but still I don't think that the front page is a podium of questions. It's simply a list of the active ones. By the way, with this discussion we are keeping the question in the front pages.

Comment: @rubik Actually, it's not. Comments do not bump the question.

Comment: @mrf Oh thanks I did not know that! Is there a page that explains in detail what modifies a question activity and what doesn't?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Construct an equation, given $x = $ the number of marbles that Seb has.

If Seb has $x$ marbles, how many does Kristy have? $\;\;(x + \;?\;)$

And then how many marbles does Mina have? $\;\;[(x +\; ?\;) \;+ \;??]$

Add the number of marbles that Seb has plus those of Kristy, plus those of Mina, and set equal to $30$.

Then you have an equation with one variable, $x$, that you can solve.

Answer (score 0):

s = # of marbles that Seb has, k = # of marbles of Kristy, and m = # of marbles of Mina. Then:

m = k + 5, k = s + 2, and so: s + s + 2 + s + 2 + 5 = 30. So 3s + 9 = 30 so 3s = 21 and s = 7.

Seb has 7 marbles, Kristy has 9 marbles, and Mina has 14 marbles.